# A term for "extracting essence from something"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Would there be a fitting term to describe the process of obtaining the essence out of something - not necessarily chemically (so perhaps something other than "distill"), but rather getting the essence of a concept, or an idea.

"Extract" also seems to me like something removed from the general body of the concept rather than recognising its seed/source/essence.

"Essentialise" doesn't seem to exist in the common use. It definitely makes sense though.

Comment: I doubt there's a single word for the (inherently metaphorical) process you're thinking of. And among the many ways you could express it using *more* words, I can't really see that any one would be obviously and unambiguously "better" than all the rest. So it's really a "list-type" question, and/or a request for writing advice.

Comment: the crux of the matter is  ... i agree with @FumbleFingers

Comment: what it boils down to is ... I agree with @lbf (except about capitalising the first person singular pronoun! :)

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly good to use "distil" or "distill" (US) to refer to ideas as well as to chemicals. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/distil) has

> **distil**
>
> VERB
>
> Extract the essential meaning or most important aspects of.

with some examples

> *‘my travel notes were distilled into a book’*
>
> *‘If you can't distill all your interests, skills, and role into two words, then obviously you've failed at the business card.’*

Comment: Thank you. Being completely honest, I am hoping voices will appear which will absolve me for using "essentialise" :)

Comment: You are absolved by "metal detectorists" which to me should be "metal detectives".

Comment: Haha, I see you are really making an effort to save me from doing it :D